# Delete a file tree if it is full using C

Tags: c, tree

Write a C program to Delete a Tree.

I have written a small snippet of code to achieve this, but it goes into an infinite loop

```
void deleteTree(struct tnode *root)
{
 cout<<root->data<<endl;
 if( root->lchild == NULL && root->rchild == NULL)
   delete(root);

 deleteTree(root->lchild);
 deleteTree(root->rchild);
 //return root;
}
```

I want to delete it while traversing. I know that Post Order Traversal can be used. But some other idea can be there or not?

Comment: I have written only small code. We can assume that I am passing the address of the root node to the function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Should you really call `deleteTree(root->lchild);` when there is no left child, or `deleteTree(root->rchild);` when there is no right child? How do you think that this is related to the infinite recursion?

Also: You should not delete the node first and then recurse into its children - because after the node has been deleted, it no longer exists, and you cannot really use `root` anymore (that it works for you is pure luck).

Answer (score 4):

Infinite loop? It should be access violation a.k.a SIGSEGV actually. When deleting leaf node, you just call `delete(root)` but then you don't return. So the next two recursive deleteTree calls are still executed (thus causing SIGSEGV because root should be invalid). Either add `return;` after `delete(root)` or use this:

```
void deleteTree(struct tnode *root)
{
  cout<<root->data<<endl;

  if (root->lchild != NULL)
    deleteTree(root->lchild);
  if (root->rchild != NULL)
    deleteTree(root->rchild);
  delete(root);
}
```

it would also save one function call because of early child check.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't post complete solutios to homework questions. (Apart from that, it's a good answer...)

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the homework tag. I just realized it XD

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be doing a post-order traversal that deletes the children and then deletes the root.  Maybe:

```
void deleteTree(struct tnode *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        // ?? delete root->data ??
        deleteTree(root->lchild);
        deleteTree(root->rchild);
        delete root;
    }
}
```

If you prefer to avoid the recursive calls when the pointer is null, you can test each child for nullness before calling `deleteTree()` recursively.  Then you could conceivably replace the existing `if` test with an assertion, though you'd have to worry about being asked to delete an empty tree (when the initial call to `deleteTree()` is given a null pointer).

Answer (score 1):

It should not be infinite loop but it is incorrect because the root->lchild may be null whilte the right children is not null when you deleteTree(root-lchild)

Comment: void deleteTree(struct tnode *root)
{
     if( root == NULL)
       return;
     
     deleteTree(root->lchild);
     deleteTree(root->rchild);
     delete(root);
}

Comment: void deleteTree(struct tnode *root)
{
     if( root == NULL)
       return;
     
     deleteTree(root->lchild);
     deleteTree(root->rchild);
     delete(root);
}   I am not getting the point where I am doing the mistake. Can you please explain in details